# How adapt code to work with a Tab Bar Controller

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, xcode9, swift4

I'm redoing the navigation of my app to be based on a custom UITabBarController. The tab bar opens the various ViewController. This is working fine, however Im now getting errors with the code in the ViewController that was previously working.

The new customTabBarController

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let feedController = feedVC() //Name of the view controller
    let firstNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feedController)
    firstNavigationController.title = "Feed"
    firstNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "feed_icon")

    let clubController = moreVC() //Name of the view controller
    let secondNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: clubController)
    secondNavigationController.title = "Club"
    secondNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "club_icon")

    let recordController = moreVC() //Name of the view controller
    let thirdNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: recordController)
    thirdNavigationController.title = "Record"
    thirdNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "record_icon")

    let profileController = moreVC() //Name of the view controller
    let fourthNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: profileController)
    fourthNavigationController.title = "Profile"
    fourthNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "profile_icon")

    let moreController = moreVC() //Name of the view controller
    let fifthNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: moreController)
    fifthNavigationController.title = "More"
    fifthNavigationController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "more_icon")

    viewControllers = [firstNavigationController, secondNavigationController, thirdNavigationController, fourthNavigationController, fifthNavigationController]

    tabBar.isTranslucent = false

    // Color of menu bar set in AppDelegate.swift

}

}
```

feedVC

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class feedVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var activityArray = [Activity]()
var userdataArray = [Userdata]()
var cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 10 // Sets the spacing between the cells

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        let authVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "authVC") as? authVC
        self.present(authVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}
```

The error I get is: 
Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102eb7b50) linked to the below code in the feedVC.

```
 tableView.delegate = self
 tableView.dataSource = self
```

The second error I get is related to recordVC

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class recordVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var tileRenderer: MKTileOverlayRenderer!


// set initial location in Aspøya
let initialLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 63.011018, longitude: 7.914721)

// Set the zoom level of the location
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 1000
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
                                                              regionRadius, regionRadius)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}


func setupTileRenderer() {

   // Fetching the map file from URL below. The {x}, {y}, and {z} are replaced at runtime by an individual tile’s coordinate. The z-coordinate, or zoom-level is specified by how much the user has zoomed in the map. The x and y are the index of the tile given the section of the Earth shown. A tile needs to be supplied for every x and y for each zoom level supported.
    let template =  "https://opencache.statkart.no/gatekeeper/gk/gk.open_gmaps?layers=norgeskart_bakgrunn&zoom={z}&x={x}&y={y}&format=image/png"

    // Creates the overlay
    let overlay = MKTileOverlay(urlTemplate: template)

    // Indicates the tiles are opaque and replace the default map tiles
    overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true

    // Adds the overlay to the mapView
    mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)

    // Creates a tile renderer which handles the drawing of the tiles.
    tileRenderer = MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: overlay)

}
```

This give a similar error of: hread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x10561bb50) for this code line

```
    // Adds the overlay to the mapView
    mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one you have to use `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` like below :

```
 class feedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
 ....
 }
```

For the second, You have to do UI operations on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    mapView.add(overlay, level: .aboveLabels)
}
```